# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java

List cc;

```
    cc=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(Submission_Id) AS count FROM Submissiontb").getResultList();
            lst.clear();

    for (int i=0;i <cc.size();i++)
    {
    Object []oo=(Object[])cc.get(i);
    submission c=new submission();
  //  c.setCount(oo[0]+"");
    c.setCount(oo[0]+"");
    System.out.println(c);
    lst.add(c);

    }
```

in this code oobject cannot cast java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: You can't cast a single `Long` to an **array** of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says (correctly) that you can't cast a single `Long` to an array of `Object`.  It is not a legal typecast because a `Long` is not a subtype of `Object[]`

Cast it to `Object`.

(I cannot see why you are even trying to use an `Object[]` here.  A `SELECT COUNT ...` query will only ever return one value.)

Comment: My guess is that OP is copying boilerplate JDBC code without understanding what it does, and using the form for a multi-column (or whole-row) select.

Comment: OP - If that is what you are doing, please stop!  Don't copy and paste random code without understanding what it does, and please don't ask us to fix your code that you copy-and-pasted without understanding it.  (It is better to learn to write code for yourself.  And you learn that by **actually** writing code for yourself.  Not by copy-paste.)